# Single entry point for list of APIs hosted in Azure App Service

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-api-management, azure-api-apps, azure-application-gateway

I have 7 APIs (API Apps) hosted in Azure App Service and I have a client app (SPA) which consumes all these APIs currently. For better maintainability at the client side, i would like to have a single entry point for all these APIs. Therefore, the APIs wouldn't be exposed to the client directly.

With the single entry point i can validate the authenticity (AD B2C token) of the client call and then route the request to respective API. In this case, the response from any API would return through the entry point to the client app.

I have couple of thoughts to implement this flow as below:

1. Azure API management would be a fit for my use case. However, the cost of the service looks little high for me.
2. Create one more API which would sit in-front of all the existing APIs, then it would act as an entry point of each request which comes from web app client. Here, for 'App Service Plan' a high end tier should be chosen to process thousands of request per second. I am expecting one thousand requests/second.

As i just started with Azure, i would like to take suggestions from you on achieving my use case. Please let me know your thoughts on suitable solution.

p.s, All the APIs are .net core web api (3.1)

Answer (score 0):

Since you've already crossed out API Management, I would say creating a API "traffic router" is your best solution. You could use something like [Application Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/overview) and use url routing to direct to a pool but you'll have to check the [pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/pricing/details/application-gateway/) to see if that works for you.

I would however, if it's not too difficult, place your 7 APIs into on one API project and just have the various controllers for your API endpoint. I certainly get if that's not possible. Should that be the case, I would place all API app services inside a VNet and [restrict access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions) so that only app services on that VNet could talk to it. That way, your "traffic router" API app can do the authorization and be able to talk to the other 7 API apps.